# How can I enable fedora to let my Java program access audio device

Tags: java, audio, fedora, voice, javasound

I have a problem where I'm trying to access the audio device that lets me listen in from the microphone jack. This code works under Windows with the output, `Mic is supported!`

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
Mixer myMixer;

for(int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++){

    //System.out.println("Name: " + mixerInfo[i].getName());
    myMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[i]);

if(myMixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)){
    System.out.println("Mic is supported!");
}

}
```

This leaves me to believe that either Fedora 17 or some Java security manager is not allowing me to access the port for my microphone. How do I change this? Why is it different on Windows?

Comment: Is the microphone recognized under Fedora? Open `alsamixer` and see if you have a microphone.

Comment: On the program cheese, it records my voice from the mic. I'm guessing that it has to do with Java being granted privileges.